# Animation file crashes application using SherlockActionBar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

when i adding an animation xml file to my project(i was trying scale, rotate, set) and try to launch it in Android 2.1 virtual machine, it crashed with following messages in logcat

```
05-16 00:14:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(898): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{su.k_r.tasstelecom/su.k_r.tasstelecom.CategoriesActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:1042)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:912)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:846)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListActivity.setContentView(SherlockListActivity.java:212)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ListActivity.ensureList(ListActivity.java:305)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ListActivity.getListView(ListActivity.java:290)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at su.k_r.tasstelecom.CategoriesActivity.onCreate(CategoriesActivity.java:72)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  ... 11 more
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:235)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  ... 26 more
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView.setUp(ActionBarView.java:1302)
05-16 00:14:01.861: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  ... 30 more
```

I don't even use animation in code.
Where i'm doing wrong?

In android 4.0 everything works great

Comment: what code is here: su.k_r.tasstelecom.CategoriesActivity.onCreate(CategoriesActivity.java:72)

Comment: Your R.java is probably out of date. Try "Project > Clean".

Comment: @dymmeh `lv = getListView();` if i comment this, it still crushes without any references to my class in logcat

Comment: @JakeWharton Clean project does not help. I checked R.java — reference to animation resource is present in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaning ABS project fix problem

Comment: Hello, I might have the same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008515/npe-while-inflating-actionbarsherlock-on-old-androids). How did you exactly "clean" ABS? Do you have ABS in your workspace? What if I had it imported in my Android Mavenized project?

Comment: In eclipse **Project - Clean project**. It was long time ago, if my memory don't tricks me, i created **Library project** from ABS source and this ABS project i was cleaning.