# ActionBarSherlock Error inflating class

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

i'm using Sherlock library for put actionbar on pre-HoneyComb device. Strange thing is that error occurs only on some device. Or better. It seems on emulator 2.3.3 works, but on LG Optimus P500 2.3.3 following error is shown (Android_InfocadActivity class is my activity):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.infocad.com/android.infocad.com.Android_InfocadActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML
file line #31: Error inflating class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3729)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:632)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(SourceFile:1045)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(SourceFile:915)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(SourceFile:849)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SourceFile:229)
at android.infocad.com.Android_InfocadActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:158)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.content.res.XmlResourceParser.i
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView.loadLogoFromManifest(SourceFile:286)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(SourceFile:193)
... 27 more
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(SourceFile:1045)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(SourceFile:915)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(SourceFile:849)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SourceFile:229)
at android.infocad.com.Android_InfocadActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:158)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3729)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:632)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.content.res.XmlResourceParser.i
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView.loadLogoFromManifest(SourceFile:286)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(SourceFile:193)
... 27 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(SourceFile:1045)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(SourceFile:915)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(SourceFile:849)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SourceFile:229)
at android.infocad.com.Android_InfocadActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:158)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3729)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:632)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.content.res.XmlResourceParser.i
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView.loadLogoFromManifest(SourceFile:286)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(SourceFile:193)
... 27 more
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.content.res.XmlResourceParser.i
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView.loadLogoFromManifest(SourceFile:286)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(SourceFile:193)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(SourceFile:1045)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(SourceFile:915)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(SourceFile:849)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SourceFile:229)
at android.infocad.com.Android_InfocadActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:158)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3729)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:632)
```

In my code, error is shown when setContentView is called.
This is xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainRootLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/myCustomTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/DarkGray" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="left" >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/main_scadenze"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_notify_title" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/main_nfc"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_nfc_title" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/main_offline"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_offline" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/checkLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/SteelBlue" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_filter" />
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/ticketBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="Ticket" />
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/NCbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="NC" />
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/PlanBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Plan" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/orderLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sort_icon" />
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/tipo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="Prot." />
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/edificio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:text="Edificio" />
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/urgenza"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:text="Urgenza" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTab1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/buttonLayoutTab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTab2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/myWorkList"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
              <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/buttonLayoutTab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
             <ViewFlipper
                    android:id="@+id/viewFlipperChiusi"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_flipper_chiusi"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >
                     <Button
                            android:id="@+id/SincronizzaButton"
                            android:layout_width="115dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:background="@drawable/aqua_button"
                            android:text="SINCRONIZZA"
                            android:textColor="@color/White"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/listInterventiChiusi"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                        </ListView>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_flipper_risolti"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:text="Storico lavori:"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/listRisolto"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                        </ListView>                    
                   </LinearLayout>
                </ViewFlipper>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

This is little piece of code:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){

            Log.i("VERSION.SDK_INT", "NON e' ICS !!!!");
            this.setTheme(com.actionbarsherlock.R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.show();
            ....
    }
```

This is Proguard file:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-dontwarn android.support.v4.view.**
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

#ACRA specifics
# we need line numbers in our stack traces otherwise they are pretty useless
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# ACRA needs "annotations" so add this... 
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# keep this class so that logging will show 'ACRA' and not a obfuscated name like 'a'.
# Note: if you are removing log messages elsewhere in this file then this isn't necessary
-keep class org.acra.ACRA {
    *;
}

# keep this around for some enums that ACRA needs
-keep class org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode {
    *;
}
-keepnames class org.acra.ReportField {
    *;
}

# keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
{
    public void addCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public void putCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public void removeCustomData(java.lang.String);
}

# keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
{
    public void handleSilentException(java.lang.Throwable);
}
```

By the way, error seems coming from Sherlock library.

I red [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608359/animation-file-crashes-application-using-sherlockactionbar) and [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/actionbarsherlock/i6fGbZn-m_M/WkDIheuXhAYJ) but error is little different compared to mine. In their code i see a *NullPointerException*. In mine there is a *NoSuchMethodError: android.content.res.XmlResourceParser.i* instead. Hope someone can help me

Comment: No solution found yet. For now i solved by implementing my custom actionBar version.

Answer (score 1):

You should not include such a view in your layout. If you wish to have a SherlockActionBar, simply extends your `Activity` class from `SherlockActivity`, and apply the theme to your application in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
```

You will then have an ActionBar.

Comment: Already set in this way. I adopted tutorial on actionbarsherlock site. If i had not extended my activity as SherlockActivity, immediately compiler would shown an error on "getSupportActionBar". So, i didn't include it such a view.

Comment: @kinghomer Sorry didn't look carefully about the logcat :p can you tell me what is line 158 of your Android_InfocadActivity activity?

Comment: No problem! Line-158 is my setContentView(R.layout.main). I red somewhere problem can be animation. I have to try if animation class and viewFlipper can be guilty

Answer (score 0):

Use the newest android support libary.

Copy this:
...\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v13\android-support-v13.jar

Into your libs folder (from actionbarsherlock) and delete the old one!

Comment: Why would this solve the problem? Isn't ActionBarSherlock already including support-v4? Just because I probably have the same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008515/npe-while-inflating-actionbarsherlock-on-old-androids)